# Does The JAUD1 cable come with the MoBo or with the PSU?

Tags: audio, motherboard, power-supply

I have a MSi X570 A Pro with a 1650 super and a 2700x.(PSU is PowerSpec 750watt 80+ gold fully modular power supply.) I found the JAUD1 port on the MoBo itself but I couldn’t find the cable that goes along with it. Does it come with the MoBo or the PSU, or do I have to buy it separately?

Answer (score 0):

Neither.

PSU stands for Power Supply Unit, its what gives the system power.

JAUD1 is the Audio interface on the motherboard, such that the case can have headphone jacks connected to the motherboard, so you can patch through the audio from the on-board soundcard to the front of the computer, rather than the rear. The JAUD1 is optional though.

So where does the cable come from? Its attached to your computer case if it supports it.

Comment: Does the NZXT H510 Support it?

Comment: I dunno. Look if the case has headphone jacks on the front. If so, yes. If not, then no.